# Collecting reviews from Walmart API

Tags: walmart-api

I am trying to collect reviews from Walmart API using the URL:
http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/reviews/10307695?apiKey={apiKey}&format=json

The api returns results page wise.Another parameter page={pagenumber} can be added to the url.
http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/reviews/10307695?page={pagenumber}&apiKey={apiKey}&format=json

The problem is the product has around 21000 reviews but the API returns only reviews until page number 25(125 reviews). Is there a way to collect all the reviews?

Comment: Documentation seems kinda bad, the official docs don't even mention anything about pagination. Have you tried adding a `&start=` parameter? e.g. `&start=125` to start at the 125th review?

Comment: @confetti I tried adding the start parameter. It doesn't seem to make any difference